# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Dname, recipe_diet}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I can get all my api info, but when create a new "recipe" and I try to show it on the Front, I get that error, but just on the "recipe" that I created, :c

```js
import React from "react";
import './estilos/Cartita.css'

export default function Card({image, title, diets, healthScore, createdInBd, id}){

return (
    <div className="containerr">

<div className="card">
    <h2>{id}</h2>


        <img src={image} alt="img not found" width="200px" height="250px"/>



<h2>NOMBRE:</h2>
<h5>{title}</h5>
<p>Tipo de dieta</p>
<div >
{
(!diets.length)?
<span>This Recipe doesnt have a diet
</span> : 
 
 diets.map((diet) => (
 
 <span><li key={diets}> {diet}</li></span>
                        )
                    )}
 </div>

<h2>HEALTSCORE:</h2>
<h5>{healthScore}</h5>


<h5>{createdInBd}</h5>
</div>
   </div>
);

}
```

and this is the Api info, the top one is from the api and the other one is the one that I created:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUPgJ.png)

Comment: `diets` as depicted on the top is supposed to be an array of string (and you're using it like so in your jsx). But on the bottom one, its an array of objects.

Comment: How can I change it? sorry Im new at this 8(

Comment: Depends on how are adding the diets data to the store / state. I believe you're receving everything from the api as array of strings. But when you add it on the frontend to state you're adding the entire response instead of only adding `Dname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

due to your screenshot `diets` can be array of strings or array of objects, therefore you need to check if `diet` is an object

```
 {!diets.length ?
  <span>This Recipe doesnt have a diet</span> : 
  diets.map((diet) => (
    <span><li key={diet.id}>{typeof diet === 'string' ? diet : diet.Dname}</li></span>
    )
  )}
```